# Which sports persons have more developed calves/ calf muscles due to sport activity & training protocols/ exercises?

Tags: calf

Which sports persons tend to have more developed calves/ calf muscles due to the sport activity & training protocols/ exercises?

I'm asking who has them, and what kind of activity, workouts, protocols are responsible for such

Update title to ensure it was not limited to Track & Field when I used the word athletes.

Comment: I don't know, but cyclists traditionally have pretty massive calves.

Comment: Anecdotally I want to say long distance runners. Determining a reliably accurate answer to this question would prove difficult however. In theory you could simply look at pictures of hundreds of athletes, but that alone might not be as reliable as measurements which I doubt are going to be readily available.

Comment: Soccer players usually on average have thicker upper legs compared to say cricket players. So I'm sure there's patterns that Optimize calf muscles too. I'm guessing volleyball, basketball & certain athletics that involve jumps are more likely to create such stimulus

Comment: @DeeV Cyclists? Hmm.. will look up that as I wasn't aware of that at all

Comment: @AlexS - Cyclists, and track cyclists more than road cyclists, and track (cycling) sprinters more than pursuit riders. Also speed skaters, pretty much any sport where pushing away with the toes powerfully is a premium will have well developed calves.

Comment: Although, this is not really a good Fitness SE question. There is nothing about workout programs in it, it's just an academic interest type question.

Comment: @JohnP I'm asking who has them, and what kind of activity, workouts, protocols are responsible for such

Comment: @AlexS - I can see that. IMHO, that would make it extremely broad, as you would be asking about the workout routines of potentially several different sports. I think there is an interesting core there, just not sure how to get to what I think you want. (Which is why no DV or VTC :} )

Comment: Which is? Ps: we got one answer that pointed out how gym exercises failed him while certain track protocols did for him that the former did not. So far he hasn't detailed them but that would be great

Comment: Also wide net is to figure out what natural sport patterns come handy here; is it heavy load + less reps? More horizontal or vertical movement; explosive jumps etc.. all these words are limiting because sports people have complex multi patterned movements.. to dissect decode and decipher which parts & directions are causing this is a deterministic question.. it's not non deterministic as you seem to think

Comment: Problem is the answer may not be easy & directly garnered because maybe no one asked or researched in such an angle before?

Answer (score 2):

Sprinting is very tough on the calves. I've been running the 100, 200, and 400m races for several years now, training 4-5 times per week.

Previously I had been doing calve raises extremely frequently at the gym without too much improvement. Upon starting track, I noticed a significant increase in the size and strength in my calves.

Comment: Was this inspite of doing other "gym" exercises for Legs in addition to calf raises; i.e. Squats etc?

Comment: Please do share what specific things and training details and differences were responsible for it